# how to scale the text according to the browser window size

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

Whenever user decreases the window size the text changes according to the window size. But when I decrease the window size it goes over to the image. I tried media queries but It always shows the same. I used the VW and vh to resize according to the window size. [image]

I am getting like this. How to solve that error. The media query I used is

```
@media screen and (max-width: 760em) and (max-height: 780em){
    .text {
        font-size:10em;
    }
```

How to solve that .

My code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>deyaPay</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion One' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Palanquin Dark' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira Sans Extra Condensed' rel='stylesheet'>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
  body {
      font: 400 15px Lato, sans-serif;
      line-height: 1.8;

  }
  .carousel-control.right, .carousel-control.left {
      background-image:none;
      color: #32CD32;
  }
  .carousel-indicators li {
      border-color: #000000;
  }
  .carousel-indicators li.active {
      background-color: #32CD32;
  }

  .button {
    background-color:#000000;
    border:black;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:20px;
    margin:10px 2px;
    width:160px;
    height:20px;





  }
  /*.text {
    font-size: 160%;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  top: 180%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }*/

  .button1 {
    border: 1px solid black;

    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:20px;
    margin:10px 2px;
     width:160px;
     height:20px;





  }

    @media screen and (max-width: 803px) {
    .col-sm-4 {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 25px 0;
    }
}
    img {
      width:100%,
      height:auto;

    }
    .col-sm-8 {

      padding: 60px 50px;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 760em) and (max-height: 780em){
    .text {
        font-size:10em;
    }

    /*@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .text {
        font-size: 70px;
    }*/

  /*@media screen and (max-width:760em) {
    .img {
        font-size: 150px;
    }*/
    @media screen and (max-width: 803em) {
    .col-sm-4 {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 25px 0;
    }
    .btn-lg {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style = "background:#FFFFFF">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <!-- <img src="Assets/img/deyapayiconandroid@3x.png" alt="logo" style="width:60px;"><br> -->
       <h1 style = "font-family:Passion One;color:#3393E7;">deyaPay</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="signup.html" class = "button" style ="color:white;text-align:center;padding:15px 20px 30px;">Signup</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.html" class="button1" style ="text-align:center;padding:15px 20px 30px;"> Login</a></li>
      </ul> 
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class = "container-fluid" style = "background:#FFFFFF ">
   <div class = "row">
       <div class="col-sm-8"> 
         <h2 style="margin-top: 100px; margin-left:50px;font-family:Palanquin Dark; font-size:55px" >
            Pay for it anyway you want</br>
            with deyaPay </h2>
 <button type = "button" style = "background-color:#4CAF50; font-size:20px;width:200px;height:40px;margin-left:50px;margin-top:20px;text-align=center;color:white;border:none;display:inline-block"> Get Started </button>
    </div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
       <img src="Assets/img/deywalletbg.png" class="img-responsive" width="300" height="250" style=" margin-top: 150px">

 </div>
    </div>
 </div> 
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide text-center" data-ride="carousel" >
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active" style="background-color: #F2F2F2">
    <div class = "container-fluid"> 
    <div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-sm-4">
     <img src="Assets/img/first.png" class="img-responsive" width="300" height="250" style=" margin-left:180px;margin-top: 40px;">   
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-8"> 
         <h2 class = "text" style = " font-family: 'Fira Sans Extra Condensed';font-size:3vw;text-align: left;margin-left: 60px;margin-top: 100px;">
            New Generation </br>
            Currency Wallet<br>
            To save and Secure Payment Application</br>
            We delighted o Support users for faster</br>
            payments and their valuable time
         </h2>

    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="background-color: #F2F2F2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="Assets/img/slide2.png" class="img-responsive" width="450" height="250" style=" margin-left:100px;margin-top: 40px;">   
     </div> 
      <div class = "col-sm-8">
        <h2 style = " font-family: 'Fira Sans Extra Condensed';font-size:35px;text-align: left;margin-left: 60px;margin-top: 100px;">
            New Generation </br>
            Currency Wallet<br>
            To save and Secure Payment Application</br>
            We delighted o Support users for faster</br>
            payments and their valuable time
         </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    </div>
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F0F8FF ">
    <div class="row text-center slideanim">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="Assets/img/bitcoin.png" class = "img-circle" alt="Paris" width="180">
        <p><strong>Paris</strong></p>
        <p>Yes, we built Paris</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="Assets/img/bitcoin.png" alt="New York" width="180">
        <p><strong>New York</strong></p>
        <p>We built New York</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="Assets/img/bitcoin.png" alt="San Francisco" width="180">
        <p><strong>San Francisco</strong></p>
        <p>Yes, San Fran is ours</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't post most of your code, so I'm just guessing, but are you resizing the image to the window width as well? Otherwise that would be the problem, not the position of the text.

Comment: Or, use a CSS grid and put the image and the text in adjacent cells. That way they can't overlap. Or, even easier, a CSS table with two cells. Or CSS columns, or just two inline-blocks, floats etc.

Comment: i updated my question with my code. please once look this

Answer (score 0):

The image is overlapped because it has a margin to the left as inline style. You could remove that inline style and use a media query to overwrite that. Take care that your text also has inline style which might cause problems, as you wont be able to overwrite it with media query.

Additionally, your second slide doesn't has the .text class on it, if you wonder that only one slides text changes.

Comment: i applied .text class for only for first slide because to check if it is applied to header tag or not. and the margin to the left as inline is used i wrote it in media queries but it doesn't apply to that tag. that's why i wrote it as inline style. But it overlapping agin how to retify it.

Comment: The margin-left is the issue. As long as you set it by inline-style it would not work to overwrite it. You could try to add "!important" to your style on the media query like "margin-left: 0 !important;". Thats the only alternative I could think of.